# UIATableView Always Named "Empty list"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios-ui-automation

I'm trying to set up some UIAutomation tests on the iPhone.  Whenever I execute logElementTree() on the main window, all of my UIATableView elements have the name "Empty list."  I have tried setting the name in the corresponding XIB file, but once data is loaded, the name is set to "Empty list" again.  The below is an example of output from invoking logElementTree():

```
 4) UIATableView [name:Empty list value:rows 1 to 1 of 1 rect:{{x:0, y:64}, {width:320, height:416}}]
 5) UIATableCell [name:OfferCardTableViewCell value:(null) rect:{{x:0, y:160}, {width:320, height:416}}]
 6) UIAWebView [name:(null) value:(null) rect:{{x:0, y:160}, {width:320, height:418}}]
 6) UIAWebView [name:(null) value:(null) rect:{{x:320, y:160}, {width:320, height:418}}]
 6) UIAWebView [name:(null) value:(null) rect:{{x:640, y:160}, {width:320, height:418}}]
```

As you can see, the table view is not empty.  Does anyone know how I can ensure that the UIATableView element is given a name other than "Empty list?"  Is there a delegate that I am not implementing somewhere?

Comment: write the code here to explain a little more.

Answer (score 1):

You want to set an accessibilityLabel for the UITableView.  In Xcode 4 at least, you can't set this property in Interface Builder -- so you will have to do it programatically.

Answer (score 1):

> The element name is derived from the accessibility attribute of the underlying view. If an identifier attribute string is specified, that string is used as the name; otherwise, the label attribute string is used as the name. Contrast with the label method.

Don't use accessibility label to identify elements, use accessibility identifier.

In interface builder, the identifier can be set using runtime attributes:

open `Identity Inspector` - `User Defined Runtime Attributes`:

```
Key Path: accessibilityIdentifier
Type: String
Value: <your identifier>
```